# How To Apply Inline Style and className to Same Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div that has a decently long list of styles that would look ridiculous to apply inline, however, the div takes a parameter of a background image url that will change upon updating state.

Styled inline, my element looks like this:

```
      <div style={{width: 55,
                  height: 55,
                  position: 'fixed',
                  borderRadius: '50%',
                  bottom: 130,
                  zIndex: 200,
                  backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.avatar})`}}>
```

However, when I do this, my background image disappears completely:

```
<div className="avatar" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.avatar})`}}>
```

What is the fix here?

Comment: does ```.avatar``` class has ```width``` and ```height``` specified?

Comment: You are adding quotes to the url which they shouldn't have. I would try removing those first. Secondly inline styles are the devil. You should not be adding them in the html as a rule of thumb. Why not add a style sheet?

Comment: @ElijahTate OP has a conditional `backgroundImage`

Comment: That's exactly my point. "avatar" is defined in the stylesheet but the background image url will be updated upon state change. Nothing wrong with the quotes, they work just fine inline and this is the proper ES6 way of doing things. The problem is using the both together.

Comment: @varinder yes, .avatar has all the styles that were inline in the previous example.

Comment: @ElijahTate have you tried a static URL with the className + backgroundImage combination?

Comment: @tony sorry, not sure what you mean by that. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Just to confirm, are the styles in ```.avatar``` class declared with units? like so: ```.avatar { width: 55px; height: 55px; position: "fixed"; border-radius: 50%; bottom: 130px; z-index: 200; }``` notice ```px``` for ```width, height, bottom``` and dashes for ```border-radius``` and ```z-index```

Comment: @varinder: correct!

Comment: @JessieRichardson instead of using `this.state.avatar`, just put a known good URL in to check the outcome

Comment: @tony Just tried it, no dice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a sample project with `create-react-app` and used the following code, it's working for me:

`App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {avatar: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png'}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="avatar" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.avatar})`}}>
        something here...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And the `App.css`:

```
.avatar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 130px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. Quadruple checked for errors and typos to no success. No clue why this wouldn't work on my end.

Comment: Which kind of Boilerplate are you using? Does your Webpack affects the css's?

Comment: create-react-app

Comment: And have not touched the webpack module.

Comment: Can you create a fresh project and test above code first.

Comment: yes that works. There must be something odd going on in my app with regards to configuration. I also tried a test div that takes a class and an inline style and that works too so combining them is not the issue. I will mark this answer correct. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Another thing is how you are updating the ```avatar``` state. Try to console it in the ```render``` section and find the issue if it's not updating correctly.

Comment: I figured it out! See below. Thanks for your help @salman.zare!

Answer (score 3):

@salman.zare 's answer is 100% correct to the question I had posted, however, the problem I had turned out not to have anything to do with combining a className and an inline style. The issue was that my div container was too small for the image, 50px. Here is was I added to make it work: `background-size: contain;`

So:

```
.avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 130px;
  z-index: 200;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

This also works and will not cut-off the bottom of the image if using no-repeat: background-size: 100% 100%;

```
.avatar {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 130px;
  z-index: 200;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```